# Moving .mp3 files into folders, trying to create an existing folder when it meets conditions for existing folder

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to create a program that reads a number of music files into an array. And based off their genre (in metadata), move them into the respective folder (i.e. house track would go into the house folder). If the folder for that genre doesn't exist, it should create one for that file and future ones to come.

The problem occurs when it tries to create a already existing folder, even if that existing folder is the correct one. What is the problem? New to moving folders/files so any advice would be greatly appreciated

```
music = os.path.join(home, 'Music')

print(music)

# Function that checks if directory exists
def directory_check(home, folder):
    folder_path = os.path.join(home, folder)
    folder_check = os.path.isdir(folder_path)
    if folder_check is True:
        print(folder_path + " is a valid directory")
    else:
        print(folder_path + " is NOT a valid directory")

directory_check(home, downloads)
directory_check(home, documents)
directory_check(home, pictures)
directory_check(home, desktop)
directory_check(home, music)

tracks = []
genres = []

for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(downloads):
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".mp3", ".m4a", ".wav")):
            shutil.move(downloads + '\\' + name,
                        music + '\\Tracks' + '\\' + name)


for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(music + '\\Tracks'):
    genres.extend(dirs);
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".mp3", ".wav", "m4a")):
            tracks.append(name)
            track = TinyTag.get(music + "\\Tracks\\" + name);


print(genres);

for track in tracks:

path = music + '\Tracks\\' + track;
temp = TinyTag.get(path);

for i in genres:
    if temp.genre == i:
        shutil.move(music + '\Tracks\\' + track,
                    music + '\Tracks\\' + i + '\\' + track)


    elif temp.genre == "" or temp.genre == None:
        shutil.move(music + '\Tracks\\' + track,
                    music + '\Tracks\Misc\\' + track)

    else:
        path = os.getcwd()
        os.makedirs(path + '\\' + temp.genre)
        shutil.move(path + '\\' + track, path +
                    '\\' + temp.genre + '\\' + track )
```

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\callu\Music\File~org.py", line 83, in <module>
    os.makedirs(path + '\\' + temp.genre)
  File "C:\Users\callu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\os.py", line 221, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\\Users\\callu\\Music\\House'
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. I would recommend using pathlib, instead of a combination of os.path, shutil, etc.

Comment: I forgot to mention: While pathlib is likely better than os.path, both are superior to basic string manipulations like `music + '\Tracks\\' + track`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [os.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

if you use:

```
os.makedirs(path + '\\' + temp.genre, exist_ok=True)
```

for the function it is ok, when the directory already exists.

Pay attention that "makedirs" can create multiple directorys when the tree is not correct.
So if you want to create "C:\Users\Tom\Music\Hardrock" and the directory "Tom" is not existing, it will be created as like "Music" and "Hardrock". So the whole tree is getting created. If you don't want this behaviour you should use [os.mkdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkdir) with an try and catch for the FileExistsError.

You have some problems in your later code:

```
for root, dirs, files, in os.walk(music + '\\Tracks'):
    for genre_name in dirs:
        # this is getting executed for every subfolder.
        genres.extend(genre_name);
    for name in files:
        if name.endswith((".mp3", ".wav", "m4a")):
            tracks.append(name)
            # track = TinyTag.get(music + "\\Tracks\\" + name);
            # this is not neccessary


print(genres);

for track in tracks:
    path = music + '\Tracks\\' + track;
    temp = TinyTag.get(path);

    if temp.genre == "" or temp.genre == None:
        # not detected genre
        shutil.move(path, music + '\Tracks\Misc\\' + track)
        continue

    if temp.genre is in genres:
        # no need of creating new directories
        shutil.move(path, music + '\Tracks\\' + temp.genre + '\\' + track)
        continue

    # we come to here because the genre of the track is new
    # path = os.getcwd()  # why this?
    os.makedirs(music + '\Tracks\\' + temp.genre, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.move(path, music + '\Tracks\\' + temp.genre + '\\' + track)
```

EDIT: corrected my answer.

Comment: Ahh thank you! That makes perfect sense. Only problem now is that it only does this for the first track in the list of tracks. I've had other results but no more than a couple which is weird.

Comment: How it is doing now?

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:\\Users\\callu\\Music\\Tracks\\Back_to_the_old_school_Original_Mix.mp3' and half the breakbeat tracks have gone into a folder called 'art rock' which i have no idea where that's coming from

Comment: ok that's crazy. Where did the exception occur and does the mentioned file exist? Second these tracks seems the have the 'art rock' genre in there metadata.

Comment: I think the source of the bug is when there is nothing in genre. but neither is the genre null or "" so it must be doing something else?